# Module separate from the rest of the bundle

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to pass as an argument a module written in typescript, `my-processor.ts` that I have to load dynamically in an angular project.

```ts
await addModule('my-compiled-processor.js')
```

The key caveat here is that `'my-compiled-processor.js'` must exist at run time. I am able to do achieve this by compiling the module manually and saving it to the `assets` folder, but I want this to be managed by the build process.

How to tell the compiler/bundler, using `tsconfig.*.json` or `angular.json` I would imaging. To process this file and let it available for download separately?

Or even better could I have the compiled module as a string in the main bundle?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

not quite sure I fully understand your use case.

If you want to load a module asynchronously / dynamically, all you need to do is wrap it in an `await import` for example like

```js
const {StuffYouWantToExtract} = await import('./your-module.module');
```

Just put this in your method or wherever you want to have the trigger for this being loaded. The angular-cli will automatically wrap `your-module.module` file in a separate donwloadable file

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

However, I think it doesn't answer my question, you didn't tell me how to get `./your-module.module` compiled.

Would this work if the import inside another function?

async function addModule(name) { await import(name) }

Comment: yes that's exactly you are supposed to do it. put it in a function. I don't understand the compile part of the question. the angular-cli is going to compile it, like everything else

Comment: The compulation part is the core of my question. I don't want it to be compiled like everything else, I want to compile that to a separate resource.

Comment: For instance, you would be able to download it as a script if you wanted.

Comment: what do you mean? The angular-cli will compile it into a separate file, that you can separately download/upload wherever you want